# How to use coordinates in PDF iFrame in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coordinates, pdf-viewer

I'm getting coordinates from API. Basically, I have two wrapper boxes:

- First box using for PDF viewer (iFrame).
- Second box using for `<form>` with few input fields.

So we have few input fields inside `<form>`

When user will focus on any field then a section should be highlight in pdf iframe behalf of focused field.

For this I have coordinates that is coming from api as given below.

```
{
    "value": "First Name",
    "coordinates": "0.46633508801460266, 0.25081968307495117, 0.510421734303236, 0.25954175740480423",
},
{
    "value": "Last Name",
   "coordinates": "0.24096687138080597, 0.25076448917388916, 0.28581652790308, 0.2595398360863328",
}
```

I'm not able to understand how coordinates will work. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The pdfviewer in an iFrame, may if its older Desktop Acrobat accept co-ordinates, but from memory only one of Chrome or Firefox uses similar way up, (Probably Firefox) for quick answer skip to the bottom that's scroll down by unknown amount of your co-ordinates :-)

Firefox allows search for text directions.

```
<iframe id="pdfImage" width="600px" height="600px" class="pdf" src="http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf#search=specialization"></iframe>
```

http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf#search=specialization

But Chrome (with or without acrobat) did not on last time tested see
[How to enable PDF search option using embed or Iframe in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73294321/how-to-enable-pdf-search-option-using-embed-or-iframe-in-html/73299830#73299830)
and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72791448/10802527

Also see https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-discussions/pdf-name-destination-not-working-on-chrome-browser/m-p/11733954

So Edge may be different, gut feeling it is say 50% reliable in my tests for going to a page, however Firefox seems to be best of all, very reliable such as here.

[image]

**Note** there is not much value in this method other than start user at ONE known point in the file, since any refresh to a second location, would most likely trigger another download thus losing any clients field data entry.

Now for your answer in above context, you need to convert any co-ordinates into browser viewport relative to the media scale so here by way of example we can tell Edge to jump to a given area at 60, however the result can be atrocious.

[image]

A different signed value is needed for Firefox (700) but at same scale

[image]

**So, both browsers use opposing co-ordinate systems, thus no use to a website without double or triple the effort.**

FireFox to jump to a given scaled area.
https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=1&view=fitH&zoom=200,0,745
Edge to go to same area
https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=1&view=fitH&zoom=200,0,70
Chromium with auto navbar
https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=1&view=fitH&zoom=200,0,120